# Different last_seq when calling changes, with a limit

Tags: couchdb

I'm querying the changes feed using the python library, and I intend to paginate through the changes
by setting the since parameter equal to the last_seq of the previous changes call. I would like to see all the changes.

`r = view('xx/xx', since=0, limit=10, feed='longpoll', include_docs=True)`

For curiosity I did the above call several times, and the results had a different 'last_seq' each time.
Though calling it enough times and the 'last_seq' will start repeating.

What's happening here ? And will my approach work ?

### Expected Behavior

I would expect the 'last_seq' to be deterministic with each call ?

Comment: Which version of CouchDB are you using? In CouchDB 1.6, the last_seq is deterministic, but if you query for a seq that is too high, it will just repeat the `since` parameter. So `http://localhost:5984/db/_changes?since=1000000` would return a last_seq of 1000000 even if you only have, say, 10 documents in your db.

Comment: I also checked with CouchDB 2.0, which delivers a non-numeric last_seq, but it is still deterministic, as long as there are no writes in between.